# PrimeNG/Chart.js - max Number of labels to show

Tags: typescript, chart.js, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG charts (based on chart.js).
I know want to set the maximum number of LABELS to show. 
The docs show this: 
ticks.max   String  -   The maximum item to display. Must be a value in the labels array

but I don't know where to put it and couldn't find anything anywhere in the interwebs. 
My chart options look like this right now:

```
this.options = {

            animation: false,
            legend: {
                display: true,
                labels: {
                    boxWidth: 0,
                }

            },

            scales: {

                yAxes: [{

                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: "ms"  
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        suggestedMax: 100,
                    }

                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: "sec"
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,

                    }
                }]

            }
        }
```

I've tried adding ticks.max on different places in my options, but I always get a "unexpected token" error. 
I can set a "max" value within "ticks", but this hast do be a number and is not what im looking for. 
And, also, the docs above tell that ticks.max is a string from the labels array. So the "max" value within the ticks object definitely has to be something else.

This might be a stupid question, but I was searching for very long time and couldn't help but ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation if you want to create a `Category Scale` should work like this:

```
.....

        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: "ms"  
                },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    suggestedMax: 100,
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: "sec"
                },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    max: "a-value-from-array"
                }
            }]
        }
```

I'm tempted to guess that you are using a notation like:

```
var y = { ticks.max: "hello" }
VM181:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

I think that explains your error.

Comment: Oh dear. I was like 100% sure that I've tried that.. >.> But yeah, it works. Me sorry. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to help you.